# Android push notification setLargeIcon not working and Icon not showing FCM

Tags: android, android-studio, android-notifications

I was checking with Build.VERSION which is greater than android Lolipop version by if statement to make sure the icon can appear on the notification right hand side.

I have used

> setLargeIcon()

but there are nothing icon or image showing on the notification. Why?

[image]

**Below is my code:**

```
    String senderImage = "https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/tom-757419.png";
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(senderImage);
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)   //Automatically delete the notification
                    .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                    .setChannelId(id)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_app)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                    .setContentText(notificationBody)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri);
    } else {
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)   //Automatically delete the notification
                .setChannelId(id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_app)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setContentText(notificationBody)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri);
    }


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

The function convert url to bitmap as below:

```
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```